# Implementing a fixed size virtual UI card

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to implement a virtual UI ID card that would look like a card on all devices. I will need 4 rows total and 3 columns. I also would like to have the width about twice the size of the height (2:1 ratio).

> 1) I considered the border layout. but it seems like it spans the whole screen size. Quickly the size of my card width was like 5 times the size of the height. So that did not visually work.  I suspect the Gridlayout would suffer from similar issues.
>
> 2) I used the table layout (4 X 3). I tried using padding / margin and it seems like the look & feel of the card UI quickly gets out of proportion on tablets while looking decent on phones since phones seem to naturally have a similar width to a card.
>
> 3)I tried specifying widthPercentage as a constraint on the table UI. Again this approach sufferred from similar issues. Since on smaller phones I would have to remove add small percentage margins but on big tablets I may need bigger margins. This can get quickly challenging to get right / test.

I am thinking now of attempting to take one of the following approaches:

> 1) I am not sure if there is a way to specify the TextField width based on the number of characters. For example when the card issue date grows on tablet it can fit 10s of characters where I want it to fit only couple for moht(mm) and 4 chars for year(yyyy). Is there a way to do that?
>
> 2) Can I tell the screen width in inches or mm ? I can implement a function to attempt and scale padding / margins on different screen size.

I appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

See the Kitchen Sink demo which has the default "cards" mode in the start. It uses grid layout with special cases to fit the columns in a sensible way for Tablets/Desktops.

https://www.codenameone.com/demos-KitchenSink.html